# Setting up travis ci with phoenix + heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, travis-ci, phoenix-framework

I'm running into issues with automating deployments with Travis CI to Heroku for my Phoenix app. Here's Travis CI build error:

```
(Mix) The database for AgilePulse.Repo couldn't be created: tcp connect: connection refused - :econnrefused
```

Here's my `.travis.yml` config:

```
language: elixir
elixir:
  - 1.3.2
otp_release:
  - 19.0
sudo: false
addons:
  postgresql: '9.5'
notifications:
  email: false
env:
  - MIX_ENV=test
before_script:
  - cp config/travis_ci_test.exs config/test.secret.exs
  - mix do ecto.create, ecto.migrate
```

Here's my `travis_ci_test.exs`:

```
use Mix.Config

# Configure your database
config :agile_pulse, AgilePulse.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  username: "postgres",
  password: "",
  database: "travis_ci_test",
  hostname: "localhost",
  pool: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Additional info:

- GitHub repo: https://github.com/cscairns/agile-pulse-api

Comment: Could be that PostgreSQL is not ready yet? You could just add a [`pg_isready`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pg-isready.html) call before you connect to make sure it waits for the service to be available.

Comment: thx for the suggestion...gave it a shot, but didn't work :/

Comment: Please, edit your question to show exactly how it is now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a second look: judging by the travis log you posted, looks like you're bootstrapping an Ubuntu `12.04` Precise for your build; I suspect that Postgres `9.5` is not available on `precise`:

https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#Using-a-different-PostgreSQL-Version

Could you try switching to Postgres `9.4` and see if that works?

Comment: that seemed to work...progress is being made, but ran into a new error...i edited the question, however, what's the recommend protocol here: accept this as the answer and open up a new question? if so, then i'll revert back to the original question for others to reference

Comment: @keruilin Glad to hear that worked! Since this is solving your problem, the right thing to do is to accept the answer, because your original question has been answered correctly. The error you're now getting is something different than what you originally posted, so feel free to create a new question if you still need help. Thanks!

Comment: I would also revert the changes you made to your question's description, for the benefit of people who are having the same problem.